# Run Method of class parallely using Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

i am using java. i am able to get class names using package names and getting all the methods in a particular class by initiating the class and run the methods using invoke property, able to run the methods sequentially one after the other.

```
Class c = Class.forName(Package.ClassName);
Object obj = c.newInstance();
Method[] method = c.getDeclaredMethods();
for(Method m1 : method)
{
for(String sfunctionname :sFunctionName)
if(sfunctionname.equals(m1.getName()))
{
System.out.println("Method Name " + m1.getName());
mth = m1.getName();
meth = (Method) obj.getClass().getMethod(sfunctionname);
    meth .invoke(obj)
    }
    }
```

the structure of these class are defined as follows

```
private void class1() 
{
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();

}
private void class2() 
{
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
}
```

and so on.............

now i want to run these classes(assuming that each class is one test case) in parallel, i.e all the methods of one class in 1st thread, methods in second class in second thread and so on.. 
all the methods in class1 should be added to one thread ,execute 
same for class2 all the methods belong to it should execute in second thread parallely and so .. on..

How to do it using Multithreading .  i have gone through docs but not able to get how to use callablehere.

Note internally one method depends on other in its class it belongs should run in sequence(optional: return some value).

Please can anybody guide me in right direction

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could simply loop and create threads

```
for (final String className : classNameList) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        void run() {
            Class c = Class.forName(className);
            ...

        }
    }).start();
}
```

But I would suggest you don't use multithreading unless you really understand multithreading and it's sideeffects.